# Custom Macro to Wrap Content with and without spacing

Tags: pdftex

My question is similar to [Wrap long text content that have no spaces](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/602997/wrap-long-text-content-that-have-no-spaces) where there are two answers to wrap content such as

```
\seqsplit{ATGTCCACTGATAAAAGTACACGCTATAATTTTCAGATTGAGAAAGCCCCCTCGTTGGCGTACGCTGCAGGTCGAC}
```

or the custom macro mentioned in the answer above

```
\def\enablehyph#1{\enablehyphA #1\end}
\def\enablehyphA#1{\ifx\end#1\unskip\unpenalty
   \else#1\penalty0\hskip0pt plus1pt\relax
   \expandafter\enablehyphA\fi}

\enablehyph{dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd}
```

These work and they do the job in that the content is wrapped onto a new line when reaching the margings, however, the content is not wrapped when there is content with spacing, for example:

```
\enablehyph{some other text here to wrap dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd}
```

Using either the custom macro or using `\seqsplit` the content is not wrapped onto a new line.

Is there a way I can wrap the content in the example scenario? Either a custom macro, a new command or away to apply across the whole document.

Comment: Can you explain why having “some other text here to wrap” inside `\enablehyph` would be necessary?

Comment: Not in that case, I just want to the content to be within in the margins regards the length of the text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the idea is, because `\enablehyph` is meant to break *anywhere*.

For what it's worth, here's a version that respects spaces.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\breakanywhere}{m}
 {
  \danmaia_breakanywhere:n { #1 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l__danmaia_breakanywhere_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \danmaia_breakanywhere:n
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__danmaia_breakanywhere_seq { ~ } { #1 }
  \seq_map_function:NN \l__danmaia_breakanywhere_seq \__danmaia_breakanywhere_word:n
  \unskip\unskip
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__danmaia_breakanywhere_word:n
 {
  \tl_map_inline:nn { #1 } { ##1 \skip_horizontal:n {0pt plus 0.1pt} }
  \c_space_tl
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\breakanywhere{
  some other text here to wrap 
  ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd%
  ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd%
  dddddddddddddddddddd
  some other text here to wrap 
  ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd%
  ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd%
  dddddddddddddddddddd
  some other text here to wrap 
  ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd%
  ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd%
  dddddddddddddddddddd
  some other text here to wrap%
}

\end{document}
```

However, the output is very dubious.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here, `\enablehyphA` is an intermediate macro that separates the input into space-separated chunks and passes each chunck onto the original macro, now named `\enablehypAA`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\def\enablehyph#1{\iftrue\enablehyphA #1 \end\fi}
\def\enablehyphA#1 #2\fi{\fi\enablehyphAA#1\end
   \ifx\end#2\else\ \expandafter\enablehyphA#2\fi}
\def\enablehyphAA#1{\ifx\end#1%
   \else#1\penalty0\hskip0pt plus1pt\relax
   \expandafter\enablehyphAA\fi}

\enablehyph{This is a test dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For the more demanding inputs (macros) that the OP mentions in a comment, this token cycle is perhaps better prepared to handle the issues:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tokcycle}
\newcommand\enablehyph[1]{\tokcycle
  {\addcytoks{##1\penalty0\hskip0pt plus1pt\relax}}
  {\processtoks{##1}}
  {\addcytoks{##1}}
  {\addcytoks{##1}}
  {#1}\the\cytoks}
\begin{document}
\enablehyph{This is a test dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd}

\enablehyph{{\textasciitilde} ! @ \# \$ \% {\textasciicircum} \& * ( ) {\textless} 
{\textgreater} \{ \} [ ] \_- + $\beta$ $\beta$ $\alpha$ $\alpha$ $\surd$ $\surd$ 
$\sum$ $\Pi$ $\Pi$ $\neq$ $\neq$ $\pi$ $\pi$ {\textasciitilde} ! @ \# \$ \% 
{\textasciicircum} \& * ( ) \{ \} [ ] \_- + = \space unc mattis eget. 
Etiam vel tincidunt dolor. \space C:\textbackslash personal\textbackslash 
folder\textbackslash another folder\textbackslash space \textbackslash textcolor 
} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works thank you, however, if I use special characters in it though such as this:


\enablehyph{{\textasciitilde} ! @ \# \$ \% {\textasciicircum} \& * ( ) {\textless} {\textgreater} \{ \} [ ] \_- + $\beta$ $\beta$  $\alpha$  $\alpha$  $\surd$  $\surd$  $\sum$  $\Pi$  $\Pi$  $\neq$  $\neq$  $\pi$  $\pi$ {\textasciitilde} ! @ \# \$ \% {\textasciicircum} \& * ( ) \{ \} [ ] \_- + = \space  unc mattis eget. Etiam vel tincidunt dolor. \space  C:\textbackslash  personal\textbackslash  folder\textbackslash  another folder\textbackslash  space \textbackslash  textcolor}

Comment: I get errors because I think it's reading it in Math mode?

Comment: @DanMaia For one, your input has an underscore `_` that is not in math mode.  That will surely throw an error.

Comment: I used `\_` and it still fails

Comment: @DanMaia Please see my edit.

Comment: Ah this is perfect but it doesnt work in latex 2018

Comment: @DanMaia You can download `tokcycle.tex` and `tokcycle.sty` from https://ctan.org/pkg/tokcycle and place them in your localtexmf or, failing that, in your current working directory.

Comment: Perfect thank you, this works