# What to do so text won't splitted on the edge of paragraph?

Tags: lyx, paragraphs, hyphenation

I don't know if my title is descriptive enough, but that is my problem. In justified paragraph some text will be splitted, like 'descriptive' become 'des-criptive' and the 'criptive' part is on the next line, I hope you understand.

Please [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75813759/example.zip) file for better example, I've included the lyx, tex, and pdf output. I don't want the text to be splitted, can I adjust some settings so it behave just like the default behaviour on LO Writer, Ms. Word, or another WYSIWYG text editor?

I'm using LyX on Linux.

Comment: Do you want the text to still be justified? If yes, see if http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31301/how-to-reduce-the-number-of-hyphenation helps (add the commands to the preamble). If no, `\raggedright`.

Comment: Yes, and it works, and now I know that feature called hyphenation, thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped -- I just found another related question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5036/how-to-prevent-latex-from-hyphenating-the-entire-document As a side note, I wouldn't do that, personally. Without hyphenation, but with justification, you could end up with very large spaces between words, which doesn't look very good.