# Can I have an "almost-non-breaking" space in LaTeX?

Tags: line-breaking, hyphenation

As suggested in, e.g., [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15547/when-should-i-use-non-breaking-space), I use non-breaking spaces in LaTeX to avoid some bad line breaks, e.g., "`the dimension of~$X$`"

However, in some cases, this leads to words being hyphenated in an unpleasant way. For instance, when writing "`Let $E$ be a vector space of dimension~$d$`", everything is usually fine, but sometimes LaTeX will decide to hyphenate "`dimension`". Yet I find the line break "`of dimension / $d$`" less jarring than the line break, e.g., "`of dimen-/sion $d$`".

I fix examples by hand when they occur, by removing the non-breaking space; but this is unpleasant because it needs to be added back whenever the text changes.

It seems to me like the correct solution would be to have an "almost-non-breaking space", i.e., I would like to be able to write "`Let $E$ be a vector space of dimension#$d$`" with some character or macro `#`, with the effect that the space should not be broken *except* if it would cause a hyphenation. **Is there a reasonable way to achieve this?**

[As TeX has a way to tweak the penalty associated with hyphenations (see, e.g., [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31309/17479)), I would imagine that there ought to be a way to specify that a line break at one point should be possible but discouraged unless a word needs to be hyphenated... hence this question.]

Comment: There is always `Let $E$ be a vector space of \mbox{dimension}~$d$`, but that, of course, makes appropriate hyphenation harder.  In such cases, `sloppypar` is an option.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: Thanks, I hadn't even thought of this! It's a good idea, but as you pointed out this will make LaTeX mess up in cases where hyphenating "dimension" is the only reasonable solution... so it's not ideal.

Comment: I'm sure there will be times when even your macro `#` will cause undesired results which you'd want to change manually. Minute irritations like this should be left for end-of-document modifications before publication.

Comment: Try `dimension\penalty1000\ $d$`.  This means that the space is a viable breakpoint but breaking will cost a penalty of 1000.  A penalty of 10000 would correspond to `~`.  (My advice, don’t try to outsmart the system)

Comment: @Werner: Yes, thanks for your point, but the hope would be that such a macro would reduce the number of cases where manual intervention would be required. I don't like leaving stuff for "end-of-document modifications" because one always finds more "last things" to change to the document in the end...

Comment: @HenriMenke: Thanks! After testing, this appears to work fine with a penalty of 100; starting at 101 LaTeX seems to prefer to hyphenate a word. Then I guess the easiest way to use it would be, e.g., to `\newcommand{\nb}{\penalty100\ }`, right? If yes, please feel free to post your comment as an answer!

Answer (score 9):

```
   a\nolinebreak [3] b
```

Has a normal space and discouraged line break

Comment: Thanks! From trying it out, this works, but the value should be `[1]`, not `[3]`, otherwise LaTeX still prefers to hyphenate the word. As per http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/94220 this is consistent with my experiments with @HenriMenke's solution in the comments to my question.

Comment: @a3nm [1] is a penalty of 51 so hardly any discouragement at all (51 in a range 0-10000) , it will be almost always do the same as just using a normal space, but if it does what you want then that's fine:-)

Comment: however downvoted, care to leave a comment saying why?

Comment: It is perhaps worth mentioning that `a\nolinebreak[4] b` (and also `a\nolinebreak{} b`) is exactly equivalent to `a~b`, that `a\nolinebreak[0] b` is the same as just `a b`, and that passing in the optional argument an intermediate value (1–3) between these two extremes yields a “proportionally intermediate result”; values below 0 or above 4 should never be used.  (**Comment to comment**: I’m not the downvoter, anyway! :-)

Comment: @a3nm: Elaborating on David’s comment, it’s true that `\linebreak[1]\space` charges a “penalty” of 51 (arbitrary units) for breaking the line at the `\space`, but, on the other hand, a break at a hyphen (inserted during hyphenation) is charged 50 units under the conventions usually adopted by LaTeX.  Thus we see that `[1]` does correspond to the minimum penalty value that will make TeX prefer the break at the `\space` over the break at the hyphen, if this does not otherwise affect the “badness” of the lines being formed (actually, the total demerits, but this would be a pretty long story…).

Comment: Correction to [my previous comment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/345284/can-i-have-an-almost-non-breaking-space-in-latex#comment847265_345304): `a\nolinebreak[4] b` is exactly equivalent to `a~b`, but `...end of sentence.\nolinebreak[4] New sentence...` is *not* equivalent to `...end of sentence.~New sentence...`!

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti yes `~` is like `\nobreak\ ` rather than `\nobreak\space` so ignores spacefactor