# word break in Justifying

Tags: horizontal-alignment, formatting, text, report

The words break in fully justification of text in latex.
I need document format "Report" and fully justified text. My latex code is

```
\documentclass[12 pt]{report}

\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{ a4paper}

\usepackage{siunitx} % Required for alignment
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{flushleft}

\justifying

\chapter*{  Abstract}

Banana (\textit{Musa paradisiacal L}) is the fourth most important crop in the world after rice, wheat and maize. Banana cultivation in Nepal is more popular like other agricultural products and has annual production of about 5000 tons. There are large plantation in Kailali and Nawalparasi districts and other districts as well. The thick, fleshy and fibrous pseudo stems that are leftover after harvesting the bananas can be used to extract high quality fiber. Farmers usually throw away this whole stump because it is big and heavy and takes a long time to rot and the animals do not eat it. Research shows, about 10-13 stem of banana can provide 2 Kg of fibre worth of about Rs.500. Usually farmers are extracting banana fibres manually or the machine costs expensive when bought from other countries as such machines are not manufactured in Nepal. Our group have studied the feasibility of developing such machine with low cost which ultimately provides opportunity of local entrepreneurship to farmers and helps in proper utilization of agricultural management. Along with it, this encourages farmers to cultivate more banana and makes country self-dependent in fibre.  \newline
\\ \textbf{Keywords : Banana fibre, 5000 tons , manual extraction, 10-13 stem produce 2Kg fibre ,  Extraction machine}
\end{flushleft}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I don't want the encircled text to break.

Comment: welcome to tex.se! you have mess of  environments/commands `flushleft` and `justify` . remove them.

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31301/how-to-reduce-the-number-of-hyphenation, if answers there can help you.

Comment: the question is a bit confusing. Justified text is the default, and the only purpose of the `flushleft` enviornment is to disable that. The non standard `\justifying` command just undoes the settings of `flushleft` so `\begin{flushleft}\justifying` does nothing useful, just adds some vertical space. You _could_ dispable hyphenation while still justifying but then tex will have to over-stretch the white space and the result will be typographically horrible. Are you sure you want that? (But the link Zarko gave will show how to do that)