# Is there a way to force a non-breaking space to an entire document?

Tags: spacing

I have finished my report but the automatic breaking happens in the middle of the words and I would like to know if there is a command for the entire document to avoid these kind of stuff ?

[image: This image shows that the breaking happens in the middle of the words]

Comment: What do you mean "automatic breaking"? Hyphenation? I can't read that language

Comment: A non-breaking space is a space where no line breaking should take place. Therefore, hyphenation of words would be necessary if all spaces in a text were non-breaking spaces. But then again, you say you don't want hyphenation (= "automatic breaking in the middle of words"). So, it is unclear to me what exactly you want to achieve. Less hyphenation usually comes with larger spaces between words, especially in languages with long words. See this question regarding how to reduce hyphenation: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31301/47927 .

Comment: Such a requirement goes against all rules of typography.

Comment: Similar: [How to prevent LaTeX from hyphenating the entire document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5036)

Comment: If you really like avoid hyphens  like in "transport-",  then the  title/question is misleading. Please change it. Avoid  hyphens always have the cost of a ragged left margin, or a horrible spacing between words. I suggested you to learn about `microtype` package and hyphenation penalties to reduce (not avoid)  some word breaks and still maintain decent typography in a justified paragraph.