# Table of contents: section titles ragged right

Tags: table-of-contents, horizontal-alignment

In the standard `book` class, if there are very long section titles, `\tableofcontents` tries to produce justified text.

How can I produce a table of contents so that the section titles are typeset flush left, ragged right?

That is, I would like to produce something like this (note that the page numbers should be aligned):

```
1.2.2  Short title  . . . . . 42
1.2.3  Long section title
       can be wrapped . . . . 44
1.2.4  Another short title  . 45
```

(The default output is almost identical, except that Latex uses hyphenation and variable inter-word spacing to make sure that the right margins are aligned for all multi-line section titles.)

I assumed that I could easily use the `titletoc` package—just re-define the toc entries and add `\raggedright` somewhere. However, none of my attempts were successful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try with

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@dottedtocline}
  {\rightskip\@tocrmarg}
  {\rightskip\@tocrmarg plus 4em \hyphenpenalty\@M}
  {}{}
\makeatother
```

In this way you'll get ragged right text and no hyphenation.

Comment: If I replace `tocstyle` with `titletoc` plus your patch in my example, it seems that subsection entries are set ragged right, but section entries aren't.

Comment: @lockstep This is supposed to work without `titletoc`. But loading it with no special setting gives the same result.

Comment: Stupid me. And your patch *does* work for section entries in the `book` class. Upvoted.

Comment: I accepted this answer, as it seems to produce slightly better results than the `tocstyle` version—in particular, this version does not try to squeeze too much text on one line. In the `tocstyle` solution, the right margin of the section titles seemed to be a bit too close to the page numbers in some cases.

Comment: I still get hyphenations :(

Answer (score 6):

You may use the package `tocstyle` (Alpha version) which is included in [`KOMA-Script`](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tocstyle}
\usetocstyle{standard}
\settocfeature{raggedhook}{\raggedright}

\newcommand*{\sometext}{%
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
  vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
  mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.
  Donec vehicula augue eu neque.%
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{\sometext}

\subsection{\sometext}

\end{document}
```

[image]