# How to typeset the table of contents raggedright in memoir?

Tags: table-of-contents, horizontal-alignment, memoir

I basically have the same question as this one [Table of contents: section titles ragged right](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45159/table-of-contents-section-titles-ragged-right) but none of the two solutions there work with `memoir`. I want to typeset section etc. titles raggedright instead of justified.

`tocstyle` just breaks when loaded with `memoir` and patching `\@dottedtocline` doesn't do anything. I also tried to change `\cftKaftersnumb` and `\cftKfont`, either of which should work according to my understanding of section 9.2 of the `memoir` documentation but neither definition works.

Here my attempt so far, MWE adapted from lockstep's answer to the linked question.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\renewcommand{\cftsectionaftersnumb}{\raggedright}
\renewcommand{\cftsectionfont}{\raggedright}
\renewcommand{\cftchapteraftersnumb}{\raggedright}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterfont}{\raggedright}

\newcommand*{\sometext}{%
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
  vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
  mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.
  Donec vehicula augue eu neque.%
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{\sometext}

\section{\sometext}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply set an appropriate value for `\setrmarg`

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\setrmarg{3.55em plus 1fil}

\newcommand*{\sometext}{%
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
  vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
  mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.
  Donec vehicula augue eu neque.%
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{\sometext}

\section{\sometext}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: 11 seconds.. :)