# titletoc: section titles ragged right

Tags: table-of-contents, titletoc

I need to typeset the table of contents entries ragged right (instead of being justified):

```
1.2.2  Short title  . . . . . 42
1.2.3  Long section title
       can be wrapped . . . . 44
1.2.4  Another short title  . 45
```

I have already asked a [similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45159/table-of-contents-section-titles-ragged-right) and got excellent answers. There is also [another similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123163/how-to-typeset-the-table-of-contents-raggedright-in-memoir) regarding the `memoir`package.

However, this time I have to use the `titletoc` package (together with the standard `book` class), and the current answers do not seem to be compatible with it.

As a simple example, here is a definition of how to typeset section headings:

```
\contentsmargin{7mm}
\titlecontents{section}
              [15mm]
              {}
              {\contentslabel{9mm}}
              {\hspace*{-9mm}}
              {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}
```

How can I tweak the definition so that the section headings are ragged right (but otherwise the typesetting is just like what I have now)?

---

**Edit:** Full MWE:

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\newcommand{\foo}{Loremipsum dolorsitamet, consectetueradipiscingelit. Utpuruselit, vestibulumut, placeratac, adipiscingvitae, felis. Curabiturdictum gravidamauris. Namarculibero, nonummyeget, consectetuerid, vulputatea, magna. Donecvehicula augueeuneque.}

\contentsmargin{7mm}

\titlecontents{chapter}
              [6mm]
              {\addvspace{4mm}\bfseries}
              {\contentslabel{6mm}}
              {\hspace*{-6mm}}
              {\titlerule[0pt]\contentspage}
              [\addvspace{2mm}]

\titlecontents{section}
              [15mm]
              {}
              {\contentslabel{9mm}}
              {\hspace*{-9mm}}
              {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}

\titlecontents{subsection}
              [27mm]
              {}
              {\contentslabel{12mm}}
              {\hspace*{-12mm}}
              {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{\foo}
\section{\foo}
\subsection{\foo}
\end{document}
```

---

And here is a rough approximation of what kind of output I am expecting (ragged right, no hyphenation):

[image]

This was achieved with `tocstyle`, as suggested in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45164/100). However, it is not compatible with `titletoc`, and I need to use `titletoc` to control other aspects of the layout (margins, spacing, fonts, colours, etc.).

Answer (score 9):

Maybe it's something like that you want?

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\newcommand{\foo}{Lorem ipsum dolor sitamet, consectetuer adipiscingelit. Utpuruselit, vestibulum ut, placeratac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravidam auris. Nam arculibero, nonummyeget, consectetuerid, vulputatea, magna. Donec vehicula augueeuneque.}

\contentsmargin[2cm]{1em}

\titlecontents{chapter}
              [6mm]
              {\addvspace{4mm}\bfseries}
              {\contentslabel{6mm}}
              {\hspace*{-6mm}}
              {\titlerule[0pt]\contentspage}%
              [\medskip]

\titlecontents{section}
              [15mm]
              {}
              {\contentslabel{9mm}}
              {\hspace*{-9mm}}
              {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}[\medskip]

\titlecontents{subsection}
              [27mm]
              {}
              {\contentslabel{12mm}}
              {\hspace*{-12mm}}
              {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{\foo}
\section{\foo}
\subsection{\foo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

To have a *raggedright* table of contents, the `\raggedright` directive unfortunately puts the labels into the left margin, so one cannot use it. A solution consists in suppressing hyphenation `locally` with the `\pretocmd` command from the `etoolbox` package. I've also removed the negatice `hspace`s from the formatting of numberless chapters, sections, subsections, as it acts only on the first line:

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\pretocmd {\tableofcontents}{\hyphenpenalty=10000}{}{}

\usepackage[showframe, nomarginpar]{geometry}

\newcommand{\foo}{Lorem ipsum dolor sitamet, consectetuer adipiscingelit. Ut puruselit, vestibulum ut, placeratac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravidam auris. Nam arculibero, nonummyeget, consectetuer id, vulputatea, magna. Donec vehicula augueeu neque.}


\contentsmargin[2cm]{7mm}
\titlecontents{chapter}
              [6mm]
              {\addvspace{4mm}\bfseries}
              {\contentslabel{6mm}}
              {}%\hspace*{-6mm}
              {\titlerule[0pt]\contentspage}
              [\addvspace{2mm}]

\titlecontents{section}
              [15mm]
              {}
              {\contentslabel{9mm}}
              {}%\hspace*{-9mm}
              { \titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}

\titlecontents{subsection}
              [27mm]
              {}
              {\contentslabel{12mm}\raggedright}
              {}%\hspace*{-12mm}
              {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}

\begin{document}
{
\tableofcontents
}
\chapter{\foo}
\foo
\section{\foo{}}
\subsection{\foo}
\chapter*{\foo}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\foo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The first version is not ragged right; it is fully justified. The second version is ragged right, but it looks very different from the original layout.

Comment: @Jukka Suomela: Do you mean the alignment of the labels? It's an error; I'll try to fix that.

Comment: Yes, the horizontal alignment looks wrong; the indentation of sections and subsections is missing, things stick out from left/right page margins, etc.

Comment: @Jukka Suomela: Please take o look at my updated answer. As I had not changed your lengths, I was baffled by this behaviour. Finally, the culprit was `\raggedright` itself, which makes something I don't understand with the layout of the table of contents. A work around is to make `\hyphenpenalty = 10000`  to suppress locally all hyphenation.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the new version with `\hyphenpenalty` is still *trying* to make everything fully justified; you just get lots of overfull hboxes, so it "looks ragged". However, if you happen to have short enough words in the section titles, you will see that Latex is still stretching inter-word spacing to make the text as much fully justified as possible.

Comment: (To better see what I mean, set e.g. `\overfullrule=1mm` and pay attention to the lines that are *not* marked with the overfull marker.)

Comment: (Also, you can try to add `\section{Lorem ipsum}` before `\section{\foo{}}` in your example. Then you will see that the spacing between "Lorem" and "ipsum" in 1.1 is different from the spacing in 1.2 right below it.)