# How to remove justification from titles?

Tags: sectioning, hyperref, titletoc, preview

I want to remove the justification of titles: I would like the titles (here the `\section*{}`) to be left aligned. Note that I'm using `titletoc`,
`hyperref` and `preview`.

## MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}


% Layout pour l'aide
\usepackage[top=1cm, bottom=3cm, left=1cm, right=1cm, paperwidth= 15cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[active,tightpage, noconfig]{preview}
\renewcommand{\PreviewBbAdjust}{-1cm -3cm 1cm 1cm}


% Table of contents
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
colorlinks,
citecolor=blue,
filecolor=blue,
linkcolor=blue,
urlcolor=blue
}
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9290/8323
\let\Contentsline\contentsline
\renewcommand\contentsline[3]{\Contentsline{#1}{#2}{}}

\usepackage{titletoc}
%
\titlecontents{section}[0em]{\smallskip}%
{\large \bfseries \thecontentslabel}%numbered
{}%numberless
{}[\smallskip]%


% Main command
\newcommand{\titre}[1]{\vspace*{2cm}\section*{#1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{}#1}}


\begin{document}
\begin{preview}
\tableofcontents
\titre{Fonctions et notations mathématiques usuelles}
\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you should apply `\raggedright`, but how you do it depends on the document class, which you haven't identified.

Comment: It's the class `article`. Where should I put `\raggedright`?

Comment: @Colas: For future reference, please always include a minimal example that is *complete*. It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @Werner Sorry. It's done now.

Comment: the tags say you use `titletoc`.  here's a potentially duplicate question: [titletoc: section titles ragged right](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/202314/579)