# line-breaks in section heading for path

Tags: sectioning, line-breaking

I have long paths as section headings and need proper line breaks. I don't need hyphens or any break rules.

```
\section{Important Paths}
\subsection{trunk/Averylong/Bverylong/Cverylongverylong/Dverylongverylong/Everylong/Fverylong\_file\_Name.txt}
\subsection{trunk/Averylong/Bverylong/Cverylongverylong/Dverylongverylong/Everylong/Fverylong file Name.txt}
```

The only way I can archive this is to add a hspace after each char. The output is exactly what I want it to be. But this doesn't seem to be a sane solution.

```
\subsection{t\hspace{0pt}r\hspace{0pt}u\hspace{0pt}n\hspace{0pt}k\hspace{0pt}/\hspace{0pt}A\hspace{0pt}v\hspace{0pt}e\hspace{0pt}r\hspace{0pt}y\hspace{0pt}l\hspace{0pt}o\hspace{0pt}n\hspace{0pt}g\hspace{0pt}/\hspace{0pt}B\hspace{0pt}v\hspace{0pt}e\hspace{0pt}rvy\hspace{0pt}l\hspace{0pt}o\hspace{0pt}n\hspace{0pt}g\hspace{0pt}/\hspace{0pt}C\hspace{0pt}v\hspace{0pt}e\hspace{0pt}r\hspace{0pt}y\hspace{0pt}l\hspace{0pt}o\hspace{0pt}n\hspace{0pt}g\hspace{0pt}v\hspace{0pt}e\hspace{0pt}r\hspace{0pt}y\hspace{0pt}l\hspace{0pt}o\hspace{0pt}n\hspace{0pt}g\hspace{0pt}/\hspace{0pt}D\hspace{0pt}v\hspace{0pt}e\hspace{0pt}r\hspace{0pt}y\hspace{0pt}l\hspace{0pt}o\hspace{0pt}n\hspace{0pt}g\hspace{0pt}v\hspace{0pt}e\hspace{0pt}r\hspace{0pt}y\hspace{0pt}l\hspace{0pt}o\hspace{0pt}n\hspace{0pt}g\hspace{0pt}/\hspace{0pt}E\hspace{0pt}v\hspace{0pt}e\hspace{0pt}r\hspace{0pt}y\hspace{0pt}v\hspace{0pt}l\hspace{0pt}o\hspace{0pt}n\hspace{0pt}g\hspace{0pt}/\hspace{0pt}F\hspace{0pt}v\hspace{0pt}e\hspace{0pt}r\hspace{0pt}y\hspace{0pt}l\hspace{0pt}o\hspace{0pt}n\hspace{0pt}g\hspace{0pt} \hspace{0pt}f\hspace{0pt}i\hspace{0pt}l\hspace{0pt}e\hspace{0pt} \hspace{0pt}N\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}m\hspace{0pt}e\hspace{0pt}.\hspace{0pt}t\hspace{0pt}x\hspace{0pt}t\hspace{0pt}}
```

The output is:

[image]

1.1 even reaches over the end of the pdf.

I have created a simple [document on sharelatex](https://www.sharelatex.com/project/57f76d837773795f0a42ac0c).

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,fleqn]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=3cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[raggedright]{titlesec}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}

% Color definitions
\colorlet{mygray}{gray!30}

% Customize headings
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\sffamily\Large\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont}
  {\thesection.}{.5em}{}[{\vspace{.2ex}\titleline{\color{mygray}\titlerule[2pt]}}]
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\sffamily\large\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont}
  {\thesubsection.}{.5em}{}[{\vspace{.2ex}\titleline{\color{mygray}\titlerule[1.5pt]}}]
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
  {\normalfont\sffamily\normalsize\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont}
  {\thesubsubsection.}{.5em}{}[{\vspace{.2ex}\titleline{\color{mygray}\titlerule[1pt]}}]

\begin{document}

\author{A}
\title{B}
\maketitle

%Table of Contents
\newpage
\renewcommand*\contentsname{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle {empty}
\newpage

\setcounter{page}{1}

\section{Important Paths}
\subsection{trunk/Averylong/Bverylong/Cverylongverylong/Dverylongverylong/Everylong/Fverylong\_file\_Name.txt}
\subsection{trunk/Averylong/Bverylong/Cverylongverylong/Dverylongverylong/Everylong/Fverylong file Name.txt}
\subsection{t\hspace{0pt}r\hspace{0pt}u\hspace{0pt}n\hspace{0pt}k\hspace{0pt}/\hspace{0pt}A\hspace{0pt}v\hspace{0pt}e\hspace{0pt}r\hspace{0pt}y\hspace{0pt}l\hspace{0pt}o\hspace{0pt}n\hspace{0pt}g\hspace{0pt}/\hspace{0pt}B\hspace{0pt}v\hspace{0pt}e\hspace{0pt}rvy\hspace{0pt}l\hspace{0pt}o\hspace{0pt}n\hspace{0pt}g\hspace{0pt}/\hspace{0pt}C\hspace{0pt}v\hspace{0pt}e\hspace{0pt}r\hspace{0pt}y\hspace{0pt}l\hspace{0pt}o\hspace{0pt}n\hspace{0pt}g\hspace{0pt}v\hspace{0pt}e\hspace{0pt}r\hspace{0pt}y\hspace{0pt}l\hspace{0pt}o\hspace{0pt}n\hspace{0pt}g\hspace{0pt}/\hspace{0pt}D\hspace{0pt}v\hspace{0pt}e\hspace{0pt}r\hspace{0pt}y\hspace{0pt}l\hspace{0pt}o\hspace{0pt}n\hspace{0pt}g\hspace{0pt}v\hspace{0pt}e\hspace{0pt}r\hspace{0pt}y\hspace{0pt}l\hspace{0pt}o\hspace{0pt}n\hspace{0pt}g\hspace{0pt}/\hspace{0pt}E\hspace{0pt}v\hspace{0pt}e\hspace{0pt}r\hspace{0pt}y\hspace{0pt}v\hspace{0pt}l\hspace{0pt}o\hspace{0pt}n\hspace{0pt}g\hspace{0pt}/\hspace{0pt}F\hspace{0pt}v\hspace{0pt}e\hspace{0pt}r\hspace{0pt}y\hspace{0pt}l\hspace{0pt}o\hspace{0pt}n\hspace{0pt}g\hspace{0pt} \hspace{0pt}f\hspace{0pt}i\hspace{0pt}l\hspace{0pt}e\hspace{0pt} \hspace{0pt}N\hspace{0pt}a\hspace{0pt}m\hspace{0pt}e\hspace{0pt}.\hspace{0pt}t\hspace{0pt}x\hspace{0pt}t\hspace{0pt}}
\end{document}
```

Is there a simple solution to archive this?

//UPDATE:
As suggested by by David Carlisle I applied the raggedright and slash approach. It works fine for the section headings but breaks the toc for some paths. E.g.:

```
\subsection{trunk\slash trunk\slash Averylong\slash Bverylongverylong\slash Cverylongverylong\slash AdditionalCompilerSupportDefines.h}
this one breaks the toc
```

I'v created an [other sharelatex document](https://www.sharelatex.com/project/57f7b0707773795f0a42b8fe) to illustrate the toc problem.

//UPDATE:
Resolved: The package tocstyle provides a hook to apply raggedright to the toc. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45164/115878 & [sharelatex document](https://www.sharelatex.com/project/57fb46507773795f0a4331d9)

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) `\path` from the `url` package may help, need to test with your doc. `\protect\path{trunk/Averylong/Bverylong/Cverylongverylong/Dverylongverylong/Everylong/Fverylong_file_Name.txt}` wotks fine. Note there is then no need to escape `_`

Comment: Thanks daleif but this breaks the section style as it uses typwriter font.

Comment: Then you need someone to help you configure `\path`, that is a different matter of which I have to time at the moment, sorry

Comment: Had a short break, this seems to work `\DeclareUrlCommand\sfpath{\def\UrlFont{\fontfamily{phv}}}`, note the `\sffamily` in your headings are probably being overwritten by `\fontfamily`.

Comment: use `\slash` instead of `/` and line breaking will be allowed

Comment: daleif: unfortunately this does not change the font. David Carlisle: this breaks only on /.

Comment: @No3x yes I know, why would you want it to break mid-directory name, are your names so long that breaking on / is not more reasonable? (the `\url` macro will also by default only break at / and : etc, not between any letter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would allow breaking only at `/` and set the headings raggedright:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,fleqn]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=3cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[raggedright]{titlesec}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}

% Color definitions
\colorlet{mygray}{gray!30}

% Customize headings
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\sffamily\Large\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont}
  {\thesection.}{.5em}{}[{\vspace{.2ex}\titleline{\color{mygray}\titlerule[2pt]}}]
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\sffamily\large\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont\raggedright}
  {\thesubsection.}{.5em}{}[{\vspace{.2ex}\titleline{\color{mygray}\titlerule[1.5pt]}}]
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
  {\normalfont\sffamily\normalsize\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont}
  {\thesubsubsection.}{.5em}{}[{\vspace{.2ex}\titleline{\color{mygray}\titlerule[1pt]}}]

\begin{document}

\author{A}
\title{B}
\maketitle

%Table of Contents
\newpage
\renewcommand*\contentsname{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle {empty}
\newpage

\setcounter{page}{1}
\newcommand\?{\hspace{0pt}}
\section{Important Paths}

\subsection{trunk\slash Averylong\slash Bverylong\slash Cverylongverylong\slash Dverylongverylong\slash Everylong\slash Fverylong file Name.txt}
one with slash
\subsection{trunk\slash Averylong\slash Bverylong\slash Cverylongverylong\slash Dverylongverylong\slash Elong\slash Fverylong file Name.txt}
two with shorter title

\subsection{t\?r\?u\?n\?k\?/\?A\?v\?e\?r\?y\?l\?o\?n\?g\?/\?B\?v\?e\?rvy\?l\?o\?n\?g\?/\?C\?v\?e\?r\?y\?l\?o\?n\?g\?v\?e\?r\?y\?l\?o\?n\?g\?/\?D\?v\?e\?r\?y\?l\?o\?n\?g\?v\?e\?r\?y\?l\?o\?n\?g\?/\?E\?v\?e\?r\?y\?v\?l\?o\?n\?g\?/\?F\?v\?e\?r\?y\?l\?o\?n\?g\? \?f\?i\?l\?e\? \?N\?a\?m\?e\?.\?t\?x\?t\?}
one breaking mid-word



\subsection{t\?r\?u\?n\?k\?/\?A\?v\?e\?r\?y\?l\?o\?n\?g\?/\?B\?v\?e\?rvy\?l\?o\?n\?g\?/\?C\?v\?e\?r\?y\?l\?o\?n\?g\?v\?e\?r\?y\?l\?o\?n\?g\?/\?D\?v\?e\?r\?y\?l\?o\?n\?g\?v\?e\?r\?y\?l\?o\?n\?g\?/\?E\?l\?o\?n\?g\?/\?F\?v\?e\?r\?y\?l\?o\?n\?g\? \?f\?i\?l\?e\? \?N\?a\?m\?e\?.\?t\?x\?t\?}
two breaking mid-word

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works fine for sections as required but breaks the toc. Try with this:
\subsection{trunk\slash trunk\slash Averylong\slash Bverylongverylong\slash Cverylongverylong\slash AdditionalCompilerSupportDefines.h}
this one breaks the toc

Comment: @No3x well yes you'd want to set the toc raggedright as well I don't know scr* classes that well, probably has some built in customisation for that.

Comment: thanks for the hint. I'm very new to customize latex behaviour. I will try to set this to the toc as well somehow.

Comment: I was able to resolve this. See the updated question.