# underfull \vbox

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment, warnings

What do the following messages mean?

```
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+msa on input line 205.
 ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.8\tex\latex\amsfonts\umsa.fd"
File: umsa.fd 2009/06/22 v3.00 AMS symbols A
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+msb on input line 205.

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.8\tex\latex\amsfonts\umsb.fd"
File: umsb.fd 2009/06/22 v3.00 AMS symbols B
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+lasy on input line 205.

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.8\tex\latex\base\ulasy.fd"
File: ulasy.fd 1998/08/17 v2.2e LaTeX symbol font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+rsfs on input line 205.

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.8\tex\latex\jknappen\ursfs.fd"
File: ursfs.fd 1998/03/24 rsfs font definition file (jk)
) [2] [3]
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active []

 [4]
[5] [6] [7] [8

] (C:\Users\acb\Desktop\Profissional\Tese\files\tese.toc
Underfull \vbox (badness 1242) has occurred while \output is active []
```

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: The second warning is not too bad; the first one probably stems from a `figure` or `table` environment with the `[H]` option that creates an almost empty page 3 or by a `\pagebreak` command.

Comment: It would be easier to tell with a look at sources and/or output, at least for the relevant pages.

Answer (score 54):

In the abstract it is nearly impossible to give advice on "underfull vbox" messages. They indicate a severe visual problem but often they are acceptable even if the number is high. However, 10000 is a value that should always be visually checked as it means infinitely bad (in TeX's eyes).

Here is the general advice that I give in the LaTeX Companion 2ed on this subject:

[image]

Comment: You say that certain errors "should always be visually checked", but you do not explain how one can find the location in the output document that the error refers to.  For example, a typical error message that does not mention a page or line number: "Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active [3]"

Comment: @WouterBeek pages are indicated in the .log file by the page numbers in bracket, e.g. [4] in the log example in this question, so it shold be fairly easy to see (normally) during which page production that warning happened. That is not always the case is the output routine could be triggered without generating a page, but that only happens with very specialized code. The above advice is for "normal" LaTeX documents and there I don't see why that should pose a problem

Comment: The page number refers to the number on top/bottom of the page, not the physical page number in the pdf.

Comment: @TimKuipers well yes and no: formally the number in brackets is the value of counter register 0  (as an Arabic number) at the time of the shipout which is usually what you say: the page number displayed, but you document might display something different (or display nothing or displa roman numerals or ...) in the running headers footers.

Answer (score 0):

`\raggedbottom` in the document preamble usually solves this problem for me.