# Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active

Tags: errors, pstricks

I'm using TeXLive 2016 in ubuntu. I get this message for every line when I run my code:

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active
```

and it makes a pdf with size 0 byte.

[that's my code.](https://pastebin.com/pxc6BCKF)

this code works well without this lines:

```
    \def\@oddhead{%
    \begin{RTL}%group
        \psset{unit=1cm}%
        \rput[tl](-4.5,2.5){\includegraphics{t1.pdf}}%
   \end{RTL}%group
}
```

what's the problem?

Comment: Related to: [how to suppress “Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) … while \output is active”?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62296/how-to-suppress-underfull-vbox-badness-10000-while-output-is-active)

Answer (score 3):

add `\hfill` before the final `}`

the `\@oddhead` macro has to fill the entire page head to the full width of `\textwidth`  your pstricks construct (why pstricks there?) is a fixed width box so you need to add some stretchy white space afterwards.

Comment: that error solved, but I get this: ```Segmentation fault (core dumped)
 )
Error 35584 (driver return code) generating output;```

Comment: @MohammadKazemi You'll probably need to ask a new question.  While you're doing that, I would strongly suggest you put all the relevant code in the question, not in a pastebin link.  You'll get more and better answers that way.

Comment: @MohammadKazemi a segmentation fault is never due to a user error/ No input should ever segfault.  It must be a bug in xetex or xdvipdfmx (depending which one crashed) and you should report it to the maintainers.

Comment: Explaining `\hfill`, it is a horizontal stretched space in a line so that the rest gets "pushed" toward the right margin. 
[https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Text_Formatting#Stretched_spaces](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Text_Formatting#Stretched_spaces)