# Two column no spacing only in one page

Tags: two-column

I've written a journal paper of 27 pages in two columns style. In 26 pages there is a space between the two columns, and only in one page they come side by side without any space. Does anyone have an idea how to solve this issue?

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}         
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{fix-cm}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}\sloppy
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: You will need to provide us with an MWE showing actual results. You may replace the real content with a dummy one but with an effect equivalent to what you are refering to.

Comment: @Al-MotasemAldaoudeyeh I have edited my question and provided an MWE. The only difference between my actual code and the MWE is the \documentclass, which is in my code {svjour3} . However, the MWE does not showing the issue that I have. Any suggestions? Thank you

Comment: you need to show an example of the problem. Showing an example that does not have any problem does not let anyone offer you any help.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I agree with you. The only problem is I got this error in the middle of my article, and I have no idea what does cause it. So, I don't know how to put an example showing that issue. Putting a picture does not help, right?

Comment: the standard advice for making an example is start with a copy of the document, delete everything that you can delete while still showing the problems, change all the words to abc if the text is private, then having cut down the document delete any `\usepackage` if the package that is no longer used, keep doing that until you have an example small enough to post.

Comment: failing that almost certainly the log file will have information about the problem so you could show the log for the bad page

Answer (score 1):

I've had this same problem - it is frustrating because it comes and goes with the amount of text on particular pages, so is difficult to reproduce.  In my case, my log file contained a

```
"Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active []"
```

error, and I found a corresponding question: [how to suppress "Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) ... while \output is active"?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62296/how-to-suppress-underfull-vbox-badness-10000-while-output-is-active). It seems that when a page has no graphics or equations, there is less flexibility in spacing, so certain quantities of text cause a fitting problem, resulting in incorrect columns spacing.

A quick fix is to move an equation or figure onto the effected page, which will add some spacing flexibility and allow the columns to be displayed as intended.