# Three warnings with six lines of code

Tags: warnings, tufte

Using the `tufte-book` class, I get three different warnings just with these six lines of code:

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\marginnote{Foo}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

The warnings I get are

```
LaTeX Warning: Marginpar on page 1 moved.

Package bibentry Warning: You have used \nobibliography* without a following \bibliography.

Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active
```

This isn't the first time I've had issues with this class, and I'm very tempted to just give up on it.

Is there an easy way to silence those warnings or should I move on?

Comment: Warnings are not necessarily a problem, if the output looks good then you can safely ignore the errors. Of course you should try to fix warnings if you can, but if you cannot fix them then most of the time the resulting pdf will be fine.

Comment: (1) The marginpar warning is because the marginpar is prior to the start of the paragraph. It's moved to align it with the first line of the paragraph. (2) If you're not going to use a bibliography, then use the `nobib` document class option to suppress the warning (and disable the built-in bibliography code). (3) This will vary based on the actual content of your document. Adding more or less text will likely resolve this.

Comment: @godbyk Thanks for the help, I got rid of the second warning but haven't been successful with the other two. (1) Then how do I get a marginnote that is aligned with the first line of a paragraph? I tried putting some text before the marginnote, e.g. `Foo\marginnote{Bar} Baz`, but the warning is still there. (3) I get this warning every time a new page is outputted. What's wrong with the length of the `\lipsum[1-5]` text, why should I need to add or remove any text?

Comment: Using the code from [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62318/172923) seems to solve the (3) warning.