# How does this `Underfull \vbox (badness 10000)` happen?

Tags: geometry, warnings

Perhaps this is a silly question. I got several `Underfull \vbox (badness 10000)` in my document, and to find the reason, I simplified the code all the way to

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\linespread{1.25}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

And the problem remains:

```
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active [1] [2]
```

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Load `geometry` with the option `heightrounded`. I'm looking for a duplicate, I'm sure the question popped up already. And no, it's no silly question `;-)`

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62296/how-to-suppress-underfull-vbox-badness-10000-while-output-is-active

Comment: @jsbibra Not quite, that question is rather generic: this is a specific (and known) issue with `geometry`.

Comment: @campa, the `heightrounded` option does work in this example, but with `\linespread{1.25}` added, I still get `Underfull \vbox`.

Comment: rounded makes the textheight a multiple of \baselineskip but if you then make baselineskip 25% larger you would need to re-do the calculation

Comment: or use \raggedbottom so it is not necessary to make the text exactly fit \textheight

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Would this `\raggedbottom` cause any visible change to the document? I didn't see any difference in the final result, but gladly the warnings are now gone.

Comment: if you have a page that is short eg large math display that can not be broken, with flushbottom the page will be stretched so the last line is at the bottom, with raggedbottom it will not (this is the same as raggedright and justified text in horizontal direction.  Here you have text and no stretch space so it is like linebreaking with `\textwidth` 300.5 pt wide and a monospace font with characters 10pt wide: it can not work, in \raggedright each line is .5pt short but no warnings, in justified text every line will warn it is .5pt short, that is what is happening here but for vertical stretch