# Page number alignment in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices

I have a quite urgent topic as the deadline for my thesis is approaching and I am struggling with this issue the whole day.

The page numbers are not aligned properly for part of the table of context - more specifically for the part where I include appendices. Pls refer to the pic to get an idea what I mean. The alignment should be like for pp. 70, VII and IX.

[image]

I would have loved to create an example, but I am running out of time since I need to be done by tomorrow.

Thanks for your help in advance.
Martin

Edit:

```
\newpage

\pagenumbering{Roman}
% Verzeichnisse

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\markboth{List of Figures and Tables}{List of Figures and Tables}
\listoffigures 
\listoftables
\newpage

\markboth{List of Acronyms}{List of Acronyms}
\input{\WPath _acronyms.tex}    
\newpage

\markboth{List of Symbols}{List of Symbols}
\input{\WPath _symbol.tex}  

\newpage
\newcounter{mypage}
\setcounter{mypage}{\value{page}}

\pagenumbering{arabic} % Haupttext in arabischer Nummerierung
\input{\WPath _content.tex}  % hier kommt das eigentliche Contentfile mit dem entsprechenden Text
\clearpage

\pagenumbering{Roman}
\setcounter{page}{\value{mypage}}

\appendix

\input{\WPath _annex.tex}
```

Comment: Without an example there is only guessing to be done...

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you at least post your preamble? It's almost impossible to understand what's happening only from an image.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the quick reply. I edited the post and added the segment where I call the appendix file.

Comment: The posted code does not give any clue -- what's in the various files you use with `\input`? Which documentclass are you using, which packages?

Comment: Also related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49887

Comment: Many thanks to all of you, but this issue has been resolved with the below comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to increase `\@pnumwidth`which is too small to accommodate the longer Roman numerals.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@pnumwidth}{2em}% 1.55em
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\setcounter{page}{70}

\subsection{First}

stuff

\pagebreak

\pagenumbering{Roman}
\setcounter{page}{8}

\subsection{Appendix 1}

stuff

\pagebreak

\setcounter{page}{12}

\subsection{Appendix 2}

stuff

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: yes, indeed - that's it! Many thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. You might consider marking it as accepted