# How to manually set where a word is split?

Tags: hyphenation

In my article, words are sometimes split a bit weird. For example: although `ev-erywhere` isn't wrong, it doesn't read very easily, so I'd like to split it as `every-where`.

How can I do that? I tried typing `every\-where` (provided by the `babel` package), but that doesn't work.

Comment: `\hyphenation{every-where}` in the preamble should do, if you don't use language switching in the document. If you do, please add a MWE.

Comment: @egreg: That works perfectly, indeed. I wonder whether I have to do this for every single word with this problem. Suppose that I have an article of let's say 500 pages. That'll be a long list of hyphenations in the preamble...

Comment: Maybe you're too influenced by the hyphenation rules in your mother language. American English hyphenation doesn't generally require splitting at word component boundaries, as far as I know.

Comment: By the way, `\-` is a primitive command in TeX (LaTeX redefines it, but in a mostly equivalent form, when normal text is dealt with).

Comment: @egreg: Maybe you're right. In Dutch, words can be split at quite a lot of places. Do you think I should use the same approach when I'm writing in my mother tongue?

Comment: Just don't worry. If the line width is generous, TeX will hyphenate quite sparsely; if you load `microtype`, hyphenation frequency will even decrease.

Comment: @egreg: Wauw, the `microtype` package is marvellous! It places everything at the perfect place. Maybe you can collect your comments in an answer, so that I can accept it.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/586/4427

Comment: Or you could use British English. If I use `british`, I get the result you want with SLx64's example without specifying the hyphenation explicitly ;). (British English uses different hyphenation rules from American English.) I tried this because splitting as `ev-erywhere` looked very wrong to me. Since TeX generally hyphenates very nicely, it seemed plausible to think the rule might be variant-specific.

Comment: Where exactly is the preamble? I tried putting `\hyphenation{<hypthenated word>}` before `\begin{document}` but that doesn't work. I can't find the context as to where EXACTLY to put the `\hyphenation` tag

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The American English hyphenation patterns loaded by TeX/LaTeX (those by Liang and Knuth) allow hyphenating `ev-ery-where`. The British ones (by Wujastyk and Toal), only allow `every-where`. Curiously enough, the online [Oxford dictionary for American English](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/everywhere?q=everywhere) says `eve-ry-where`. Also, if we instead of the traditional patterns for AmEn we use the “US English max” patterns by Kuiken, the only allowed hyphenation is `every-where`.

Let's look for a confirmation with a test:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\test[1]{%
  \language\csname l@#1\endcsname
  \parbox[t]{0pt}{\hspace{0pt}everywhere}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lll}
American English  & American English    & British English     \\
(Liang-Knuth)     & (Kuiken)            & (Wujastik and Toal) \\
\test{english}    & \test{usenglishmax} & \test{british}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you feel that `ev-ery-where` is ambiguous, you can add

```
\hyphenation{every-where}
```

to your preamble. If you do language shifting with `babel`, it's best to use its own method for defining hyphenation exceptions:

```
\babelhyphenation[english]{every-where}
```

(you need `babel` version 3.9). Changing the hyphenation patterns to use `usenglishmax` is possible with H. Oberdiek's package `hyphsubst`, typing

```
\usepackage[english=usenglishmax]{hyphsubst}
```

as soon as possible in the preamble.

However, TeX is usually quite frugal with hyphenation, provided the line length is generous. By loading `microtype` you can even decrease the hyphenation frequency.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}

\microtypesetup{activate=false}
\kant[1]

\microtypesetup{activate=true}
\kant[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The following is not a critique of your first MWE but just an observation: your first MWE compiles as expected -- i.e., with hyphenations taking place -- under both pdfLaTeX and XeLaTeX but *not* under LuaLaTeX. (I've tested it with both MacTeX2013 and TeXLive2014/pre.) Specifically, with LuaLaTeX the hyphenation points are found in the first column but not in the second and third. Very odd (and disturbing, really).

Comment: @Mico The explanation is easy: LuaTeX loads the hyphenation patterns on demand; `babel` deals with this, but otherwise one has to do it manually. I find it much worse the fact that `hyphsubst` doesn't really work with LuaLaTeX.

Answer (score 36):

You can use `\hyphenation{every-where}` to manually set the hyphenation.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\hyphenation{every-where}

\begin{document}
everywhere everywhere everywhere everywhere everywhere everywhere everywhere 
everywhere everywhere everywhere everywhere everywhere everywhere everywhere
everywhere everywhere everywhere everywhere everywhere everywhere 
\end{document}
```