# Some words jump out of boundary

Tags: line-breaking, hyphenation, geometry

I am using

```
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 left=25mm,
 top=26mm,
 right=26mm,
 bottom=26mm,
 }
```

But some of my words jump out of my boundary. 
How can I solve it?[image]

Comment: LaTeX does not know where to hyphenate 'oxidoreductase'  so this word just flows into the margin and yields an overfull box warning. To tell LaTeX where to hyphenate words, you can use e.g. `\hyphenation{every-where}` in the preamble. (See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/182569/134144) Also related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9107/134144

Comment: You should use `~` in front of `\cite` commands.

Comment: potential duplicate: [No hyphen for a word](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/67571)

Comment: @leandriis no, latex can hyphenate the word, so using `\hyphenation` won't help in this case.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: You are right. I must have overlooked the missing spaces before the citations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

LaTeX can hyphenate oxidoreductase, as shown by the log of the example below the default US English patterns would allow breaks at any of `ox-i-dore-duc-tase`  However the image shows that you are attaching the citation directly to the word, this makes the whole construct a non-word and will be skipped and not considered for hyphenation.  It is normal to use a non breaking space `~`. Compare the two paragraphs in the output shown.

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength\textwidth{3cm}

\showhyphens{oxidoreductase}
\begin{document}

zz zzz
zz zz zz zzz
zz zz zz zzz
oxidoreductase\cite{zz}
zz zz zz zzz

zz zzz
zz zz zz zzz
zz zz zz zzz
oxidoreductase~\cite{zz}
zz zz zz zzz



\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem[1]{zz}{something}
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```