# Debugging BMC LaTeX template for personal use

Tags: templates, warnings, debugging

I use the BMC LaTeX templates for my own documents, but it always throws the warning:

```
 Overfull \hbox (1.0pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active
```

And I just don't know where it comes from... Could anyone have a look and see how to remove this warning? Thanks!

You can get the template from: http://www.biomedcentral.com/authors/tex (bmc_article)

I am not asking what "overfull \hbox" means, just how to track that warning in this particular template, and solve it!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does "overfull hbox" mean?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35/what-does-overfull-hbox-mean)

Comment: I know what overfull hbox means... I just don't know where the warning comes from in this particular template

Comment: Use `\documentclass[draft]{bmcart}` and you will see where is it. Just in in the top right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setting for `\leftarea@width` is off by one.

Workaround: after the `\documentclass` line, add

```
\makeatletter
\setattribute{leftarea}{width}{123\p@}
\makeatother
```

A more general workaround that doesn't rely on knowing the value is

```
\makeatletter
\begingroup
\def\get#1\p@{#1}
\count@=\expandafter\get\leftarea@width
\advance\count@\@ne
\edef\x{\endgroup\def\noexpand\leftarea@width{\the\count@\p@}}\x
\makeatother
```