# What is the best way to avoid overful hbox in this situation?(mathematics)

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

I am writing some mathematical symbols which gives me an overful hbox, please see the picture.

[image]
The code is

```
\documentclass[a4paper,draft]{memoir}
\RequirePackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}              
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newtheorem{Co}{Corollary}
\numberwithin{Co}{section}

\begin{document}
\chapter{first chapter}
\section{first section}
\begin{Co}
Let $\{P_n\}$ be a collection of probability measures on $(C[0,\infty),\mathcal{C})$.
Such that etc.etc.
\end{Co}
\end{document}
```

What would be a good way to fix this? One idea I have is using "align" but it seems overkill to get the mathematical symbol on a new line in the middle of the page. Are there any good ways to write this to not get an overful hbox?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Related informations: [What does “overfull hbox” mean?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35/124842)

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! The simplest is probably to modify the phrasing, so the formula goes ‘on its own’ to next line.

Comment: Write `Let the set $\{P_n\}$ ...` instead.

Answer (score 4):

This shows the problem, plus 3 ways to deal with it:

1. Specify a breakpoint manually within the long math expression, `$(C[0,\infty),\allowbreak\mathcal{C})$`
2. Invoke `\sloppy` within the corollary.
3. Reword the corollary, as suggested by Bernard and Henri, to avoid the problem to begin with.

The MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,draft]{memoir}
\RequirePackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}              
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newtheorem{Co}{Corollary}
\numberwithin{Co}{section}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{first chapter}
\section{first section}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{Co}
  Let $\{P_n\}$ be a collection of probability measures on
  $(C[0,\infty),\mathcal{C})$.  Such that etc.etc.
\end{Co}
\begin{Co}
  Let $\{P_n\}$ be a collection of probability measures on
  $(C[0,\infty),\allowbreak\mathcal{C})$.  Such that etc.etc.
\end{Co}
\begin{Co}
  \sloppy
  Let $\{P_n\}$ be a collection of probability measures on
  $(C[0,\infty),\mathcal{C})$.  Such that etc.etc.
\end{Co}
\begin{Co}
  Let the set $\{P_n\}$ be a collection of probability measures on
  $(C[0,\infty),\mathcal{C})$.  Such that etc.etc.
\end{Co}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you say that, "any good ways to write this to not get an overful hbox", I presume that you are more concerned about the irritating messages, and will not mind a bit overfull horizontal material so
long as the looks are not destroyed.

Here is one technique I employ more than often.

---

```
\documentclass[a4paper,draft]{memoir}
\RequirePackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}              
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newtheorem{Co}{Corollary}
\numberwithin{Co}{section}

\begin{document}
\chapter{first chapter}
\section{first section}
\begin{Co}
  \hfuzz\maxdimen
  Let $\{P_n\}$ be a collection of probability measures on
  $(C[0,\infty),\mathcal{C})$.  Such that etc.etc.
\end{Co}
\end{document}
```

---

[image]

---

`\hfuzz=[length]` is a parameter that allows hbox's to be overfull by `[length]` before an overfull error occurs.
When we set this to `\maxdimen`, an overfull hbox never occurs.

`\maxdimen` is the largest dimension, but not the largest 
number.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the margin overrun is not in the "epsilon" noise, but very visibly noticeable.  Add a `\usepackage{lipsum}` to the preamble and `\lipsum[1]` after the corollary to see this.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Yes, I am very much aware of this issue. But as I said, when we don't mind a bit of overshoot at the right, we can use this technique.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Moreover, whenever I employ this trick, I *never* make it global. I always make it a point to keep it scoped.