# Inserting figures into Anki (LaTeX cards) causes no BoundingBox error

Tags: graphics, bounding-box

I'm using latex to format my Anki cards and ran into an error:

"! LaTeX Error: Cannot determine size of graphic in"

```
\begin{center}
\includegraphics{supplementary.PNG}\\\relax {{c1::Supplementary angle}}
\end{center}
```

I'm using TexLive if this helps.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The `latex` executable (_i.e._ pdfLaTeX with DVI output) doesn't work with `.png` images. Try changing the executable to `pdflatex`

Comment: How can i do that?

Comment: How are you compiling your document? From the command line or using an editor? If you're using an editor, which one?

Comment: Well, In Anki we have a preview option which allows us to view the card. It works well when I use it without any images, but as soon as I attempt to implement images, it breaks. It could be that the preview function uses some default setting of LaTeX to execute the code, in which case I'm not really sure how to change it.

Comment: Oh, Anki _is_ the program. I don't have it, so I can't tell you exactly what to do, sorry. Try looking for some setting to change the TeX engine/compiler and make sure it is set to `pdflatex` instead of just `latex`. Ah, it seems that `latex` is hard-coded in the program (see [here](https://github.com/dae/anki/blob/master/anki/latex.py#L10-L13)). Try changing that to `pdflatex` in the source of the program.

Comment: If you do as Phelype Oleinik suggests, make sure to also change `dvipng` to a PDF based workflow.

Comment: Hi, I downloaded an addon for anki called "Edit Latex Build Process" which allows me to change the configuration dictionary as @Phelype Oleinik suggested. I changed under the `"pngCommands":` the `"latex"` line to `"pdflatex"` and as @TeXnician suggested, I changed the `"dvipng"` to `"dvipdfmx"` which based on my research what TexLive supports.

However, a new problem occurs. The error begins with: `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20` which seems like a good sign and this seems to be the interesting part `Overfull \hbox (1005.7175pt too wide) detected at line 27`.

Comment: @Vocaloidas That's not an error, it's TeX warning you (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35/134574)) that whatever you tried to include in your document is `1005 pt` too large to fit there (which is a pretty large amount, so it should be visible from the output). If it's the picture, you need to resize it somehow (Sorry, I have no idea how this Anki thingy works).