# A rectangular box after page number in odd pages?

Tags: page-numbering

Need to remove extra box after page number? how to do that? it happens only for odd number pages [image]

Comment: did you look at this one?  https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35/15036

Comment: I have little idea how you got the output you show. What is it? Please provide an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) that we can compile that shows your problem.

Comment: Odd pages are tight-hand pages, and often, a section heading is used as the running head.  This text is simply too long, and you need a shorter version.  You can use an optional short version, almost always permitted: `\section[<optional short form>]{<full form>}`.