# Word with accent does not respect text width

Tags: accents, textwidth

I have a word with accent: "Kleinekathöfer", also tried with: Kleinekath"{o}fer, and this word is going above the defined text width. Any insights? Thanks for you help.

[image]

Comment: You have not shown any clue about the source.... It will only be related to the accent if you are using OT1 encoding (if so switch to T1) otherwise have you specified the correct language? The US English patterns can not usefully hyphenate this.

Comment: Thanks for your help. To be honest I'm using a huge template file, I have no clue what I should be looking for to answer your comments.

Comment: make a copy of your document with just one paragraph, then delete every package not needed to show the problem, and post the resulting example here  (or simply use `Kleinekat\-höfer` and ignore for now...

Comment: Should have thought about this trick. Thanks!

Comment: Please tell us whether you employ pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, or LuaLaTeX to compile your document. Do you load either the `babel` or the `polyglossia` package? If so, with which options?

Comment: See also: [boxes - What does "overfull hbox" mean? (Why is there a black mark at the end of a line?) - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35/what-does-overfull-hbox-mean-why-is-there-a-black-mark-at-the-end-of-a-line?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: I'm using pdfLaTeX. After looking at all the different files included in this template I'm using, I've spotted  "\usepackage[english]{babel}", and no polyglossia package seems to be imported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the line

```
\usepackage[english]{babel}
```

to

```
\usepackage[german]{babel}
```

The babel package loads the proper hyphenation patterns to your document.
Another way is to provide the hyphenation pattern by hand as in `hi\-fe\-ni\-zar`

Comment: I think you should advise folks to employ `ngerman` instead of `german` -- unless they've indicated that they wish to adhere to pre-1996 spelling and grammar rules...

Comment: The question gives virtually no information but since three of the four visible words are `and`,  `field` and `server` my guess is this is an English document with a German word mid-sentence so globally changing babel not right

Comment: David is correct, \usepackage[german,main=english]{babel} fixed the issue.