# Overfull \hbox (3.10524pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 324--324

Tags: tables, overfull, message

I got numerous messages like this in even one table. I want to get rid at least some of them.

The style file can be downloaded here: [clv3.cls link (from Computational Linguistics)](https://cljournal.org/style.html). It's the first file in the list on that page.
The following is the working environment:

```latex
% if your latex compiler failed to compile, uncomment the command below:
%\RequirePackage[2020-02-02]{latexrelease}
%\documentclass{clv3}

%% the fllowing is the suggested change by David

% save the kernel \document and \enddocument

\let\latexdocument\document

\let\latexenddocument\enddocument

%%%

\documentclass{clv3}

% restore the original below \docucumentclass{clv3}

\let\document\latexdocument

\let\enddocument\latexenddocument

% add to the standard hooks

\makeatletter

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \if@filesw
    \immediate\openout\@mainqry=\jobname.qry
  \fi
}
\AtEndDocument{%
   >\ifx\@biography\@empty\else{\par\ifbrief\vskip10pt\fi\biofont\noindent\@biography\par}\fi
   \immediate\closeout\@mainqry
   %\ifquery
   %   \process@queries\clearpage
   %\else
      >\ifodd\c@page\clearpage\thispagestyle{empty}\null\clearpage\else\clearpage\fi

   %\fi
  
%\ifquery\clearpage\else\ifodd\c@page\clearpage\thispagestyle{empty}\null\clearpage\else\clearpage\fi\fi }
\makeatother

% alias numdef to cnumdef

%\NewCommandCopy{\cnumdef}{\numdef}

%\NewCommandCopy{\endcnumdef}{\endnumdef}

\let\numdef\relax \let\endnumdef\relax

%% above is the suggested change by David

\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{xltabular}

\usepackage{makecell}

\usepackage{metalogo}

\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{amssymb}

% the following two lines are added by the author to show Chinese characters
%
\usepackage{CJKutf8}

\usepackage{hyperref}

% nicer emptyset

\let\oldemptyset\emptyset

\let\emptyset\varnothing

\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0, 0, 0.5}

\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,citecolor=darkblue, linkcolor=darkblue, urlcolor=darkblue}

\bibliographystyle{compling}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Magnitude orders of English and Chinese \textit{numunit}s.}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.6}
\begin{tabular}{p{1.2cm}p{0.4cm}p{1cm}p{1.2cm}p{0.4cm}p{0.8cm}p{0.8cm}p{0.8cm}p{1cm}p{1.6cm}}
\hline
in digit & $10^1$ & $10^2$ & $10^3$ & $10^4$ & $10^6$ & $10^8$ & $10^9$ & $10^{1^2}$ & $10^{1^5}$\\
Chinese & 十 &百  &千  &万  &$\emptyset$ & 亿 & $\emptyset$ & $\emptyset$ & $\emptyset$\\
English & $\emptyset$ & hundred & thousand& $\emptyset$ & million & $\emptyset$ & billion & trillion & quadrillion\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\label{table:magnitude}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The errors read as follows, for example(see the screeshot for more messages):

```
Overfull \hbox (3.10524pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 324--324
```

More messages:
[image]
Thanks a lot in advance!~~~

Comment: again you post disconnected fragments that make it hard to help. Always post examples as complete small documents that show the problem

Comment: they are not errors but just warning that you have specified very narrow columns such as  0.4cm  and tex can not break the supplied text in to lines that short

Comment: Thanks. But beside the working environments, table codes, error/messages and screenshot, what else can I provide?

Comment: why make anyone trying to help reconstruct an example from those bits, or trace unrelated packages like `\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}`  you should have a single code block from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`  and only include packages and definitions you need  to show the problem

Comment: as you are asking about a tabular you can probbly use a standard article class in the example. it would be easy for you to checck before posting whether you get the same warnings

Comment: perhaps just put `\small` after `\begin{table}` is enough

Comment: I see. Thanks. I should have included the two pieces of code in one block. However, as a green hand, I am not very sure which prepackage could be the source of the problem though "linguistics" package indeed is unlikely  to be the one in this case.

Comment: I tried `\small`. It does get rid of a couple of the messages, but more in the same table still persist. I guess as they may not affect too much, I can just ignore them for now. BTW, I am using a standard article class. Thanks anyway~

Comment: no standard `article` class would be  `\documentclass{article}` you are using a non standard and broken clv3 class which is why you need weird fixes `\let\document\latexdocument`...

Comment: I believe you are right. I will try to undo the changes of weird fixes suggested by another expert.  It gave me another headache. :-(

Comment: Figuring out what you need in your example is just a matter of trial-and-error. You don't need to know in advance. You just comment and uncomment stuff until you figure out what's needed. E.g. comment out half the packages from your example. Compile. If the messages persist, delete those lines. If the messages disappear, uncomment half of what you commented. Repeat as necessary.

Comment: Without more to go on, the best that we can do is refer you to work through https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35/107497.

Comment: thanks for the informative links. @Teepeemm