# "Overfull \hbox" problem

Tags: overfull, bad-box

[image: This is showing the problematic Code]

I have an overflow problem but I can`t figure out how to solve it. Why is

```
\rule{\textwidth}{0.6pt}\\[\baselineskip]   
\vspace{0.5cm}
```

giving out an overfull error if the text is not responsible?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. What happens if you insert the instruction `\noindent` immediately before `\rule`? Incidentally, what's the value of the `\parindent` parameter?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Do not take screenshots of code, but paste the code as text in the form of a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). That is not an error, but a warning. See [What does "overfull hbox" mean? (Why is there a black mark at the end of a line?)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35/123129).

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 2):

I can replicate the OP's issue precisely with the following test code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\rule{\textwidth}{0.6pt}

\end{document}
```

Spefically, I get the following warning message:

> Overfull \hbox (17.62482pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 5--6

Observe that `Overfull \hbox (17.62482pt too wide)` also shows up in the warning message reported by the OP.

The fix? I suggest issuing the instruction `\noindent` immediately before the `\rule` instruction.

A final comment: It doesn't have to be text that causes the overfull-hbox warning; it can just as well be a horizontal rule.

Answer (score 2):

The overfull is caused by the paragraph indentation. Thus `\rule` should be preceded by `\noindent`.

But, as you're doing `flushleft` things just after that rule, just place the rule inside it.

Also `\\[\baselineskip]\vspace{0.5cm}` is not very good programming and `\\` shouldn't be used in that context anyway: just use a blank line after the rule followed by the desired amount of vertical space.

Adding columns in the `tabular` to get space isn't the best way too: look at the code below where a specific distance between columns is inserted.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

\newcommand{\printauthor}{A. Uthor}
\newcommand{\matnr}{176--761}
\newcommand{\abgabedatum}{July 38, 2043}


\begin{document}

\begin{flushleft}

\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}

\vspace{1cm}

\begin{tabular}{@{} l @{\hspace{2em}} l @{}}
\textbf{von:}         & \printauthor \\
                      & Matrikelnummer: \matnr \\
\textbf{Betreuer:}    & Dr.\ Daniel Brunner \\
\textbf{Abgabedatum:} & \abgabedatum
\end{tabular}

\end{flushleft}

\end{document}
```

Adjust the lengths to your liking.

[image]